# Mysql query ignoring the row if child row from left join table doesn't exists

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, left-join

Hi there so first of all , i'm not that expert in mysql queries. i have tow tables `wp_posts` and `wp_wti_like_post` and i'm doing `LEFT JOIN` on `wp_wti_like_post ON wp_posts.ID = wp_wti_like_post.post_id`  and `SUM(wp_wti_like_post.value) < 2` BUT if there is `no row`in `wp_wti_like_post` with id of post from `wp_posts` then it doesn't show even the row from `wp_posts` and just ignore it , please help in this really need it.

query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_wti_like_post ON wp_posts.ID = wp_wti_like_post.post_id
WHERE wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
GROUP BY wp_wti_like_post.post_id
HAVING SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value ) <2
OR SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value ) = NULL 
LIMIT 0 , 200
```

table wp_wti_like_post

http://prntscr.com/6xixrd

table wp_posts

http://prntscr.com/6xixzp

Comment: of course it ignores it. you're implicitly choosing only rows where `wp_wti_like_post` has a value in your `having` and `group` clauses.

Comment: @pala_ it still does same thing , it ignores the row if the row inside wp_wti_like_post does not exists

Comment: @pala_ so what can be the solution ? this is what i'm having trouble in,

Comment: probably wouldnt hurt to group by `wp_posts.ID` instead of `wp_wti_like_post.post_id`

Comment: @pala_ yeah but it does the same thing , ignoring the posts , might be because i've been checking wp_wti_like_post.value  , but the main thing is value that is needed seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i sorted this out by my self and go it working in this way

at the place of

```
SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value ) = NULL
```

it should need to be

```
SUM( wp_wti_like_post.value ) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to restructure your query to as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT WP.*, SUM(LP.value) AS `value`
    FROM wp_posts WP
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT post_id FROM wp_wti_like_post WHERE post_status = 'publish') LP
        ON WP.ID = LP.post_id
    GROUP BY WP.ID
) T1
WHERE T1.value IS NULL
OR T1.value < 2;
```

The Inner-most query first fetches only wti_like_posts that have been published.

The left-join is then performed, which will give you the expected result of fetching all rows from wp_posts, even if they do not join with a record from the sub-query.

After that is performed, the GROUP statement performs the computation of SUMming the values.

The outer-most query enforces the requirement that the sum must either be less than 2 or be null.